# I need a creative way to access followers using the Twitter API for 10,000 usernames or more without hitting rate limits, in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

How do I access the number of followers a user has on Twitter for 10,000 usernames or more each day?

Needless to say this hits the rate limit. I was told there are creative ways to avoid the limit, but I can't find any. I also don't want to use or can't use authentication of users. I need to do it as an anonymous server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give [GET users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/lookup) a try. It lets you get user objects for 100 users in a single request. 10000 users / 100 user/request = 100 requests which will be easy to do in an hour let alone all day.